# Context menu not showing up in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create a Firefox addon that adds a context menu item when right-clicking on pages.

I'm using the instructions on this MDN page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items

As per the instructions I've written a manifest.json to include the contextMenus permission:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TestAddon",
  "version": "0.1",

  "description": "Test",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["background-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "sitetimelimiter@example.com",
      "update_url": "https://example.com/updates.json"
    }
  }
      
}
```

...and in background-script.js I've written the code using the guidelines on that MDN article, with a few extra log lines for debugging:

```
console.log('mark 1');

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "test-item",
    title: "Test context-menu item",
    contexts: ["all"],
}, onCreated);

console.log('mark 2');

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    switch (info.menuItemId) {
        case "test-item":
            alert("Test worked!");
        break
    }
});

console.log('mark 3');
```

As far as I can tell all of that is in line with the MDN doc.

When I go to about:debugging and click "Load Temporary Add-on..." to test the addon, it loads the addon without any errors.

But when I load a test page in the browser and right-click the page, the test item hasn't been added to the context menu.

Looking at the console, I can see that "mark 1" is shown, but "mark 2" and "mark 3" never get logged.

This seems to indicate a problem in this section here:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "timer-reset",
    title: "Reset page timer",
    contexts: ["all"],
}, onCreated);
```

...but I've triple-checked and that syntax seems to line up perfectly with the MDN doc.

I've also seen other MDN docs that instruct me to use browser.menus.create() instead of browser.contextMenus.create(), but I get the same results regardless of whether I use .menus or .contextMenus

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to access `browser.contextMenus` in the content scripts. They are only available in a background script.

From MDN page you linked to:

> You can then add (and update or delete) the context menu items in your extension's background script.

So you need to move that part of the code into a background script, in manifest.json:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it didn't sink in at first that background scripts are different from content scripts.

Comment: Yeah, it takes a while to grasp. In simplified sense, most of the WebExtensions API stuff are accessible from background scripts and Web API from content scripts but that's not the whole accurate picture.